# Why does my box disappear?

Tags: famous-engine

I am trying to track the position of 'myBox,' at the time of a click. It works when I attach the event to myBox, but that isn't what I want. I want to be able to click anywhere within the window. I thought that since Scene has a .onReceive() function, that I would be able to attach the click event to Scene itself, but whenever I do, the box does not appear.

```
'use strict';

 var famous = require('famous');

 var Camera = famous.components.Camera;

var math = famous.math;
var physics = famous.physics;
var PhysicsEngine = famous.physics.PhysicsEngine;
var Box = physics.Box;
var Vec3 = math.Vec3;
var Size = famous.components.Size;
var Position = famous.components.Position;
var MountPoint = famous.components.MountPoint;
var Gravity1D = physics.Gravity1D;
var Collision = physics.Collision;
var Distance = physics.Distance;
var Wall = physics.Wall;


var DOMElement = famous.domRenderables.DOMElement;
var FamousEngine = famous.core.FamousEngine;

//Physics engine test
function Game() {

  //create scene graph
  this.scene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');

  this.camera = new Camera(this.scene);
  // this.camera.setDepth(1000);

  this.simulation = new PhysicsEngine();

  this.node = this.scene.addChild();
  this.node
      .setSizeMode('absolute', 'absolute', 'absolute')
      .setAbsoluteSize(50, 200)
      .setPosition(0, 0, 0)
      .setMountPoint(0.5, 1);

  this.line = this.node.addChild();
  this.line
      .setAbsoluteSize(50,10)
      .setSizeMode(1,1,1)
      .setAlign(0.0, 0.5); //need to make function to radomize this
  var mark = new DOMElement(this.line, {
    properties:{
        'background-color': '#FF0000'
    }
  });


  var position = new Position(this.node);
  this.myBox = createBox.call(this, this.node, position);
  this.scene.myBox = this.myBox;
  console.log('this.myBox', this.myBox);
  console.log(window.innerHeight);

    this.scene.addUIEvent('click');
    this.scene.onReceive = function(event,payload){
        if(event==='click'){
            var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();
            // var bp = this.myBox.getPosition();
            console.log(itemPosition.y - 100);
        }
    }


  FamousEngine.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this);
  console.log(this);
}

Game.prototype.onUpdate = function(time){
    this.simulation.update(time);

var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();

    // console.log(itemPosition);
    //console.log(itemPosition.x, itemPosition.y, itemPosition.z);
 this.node.setPosition(itemPosition.x,itemPosition.y,itemPosition.z);
    FamousEngine.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this);
};

//add node - this node will be static
//create box
function createBox(node, position) {
  //attach a DOM element component to the staticNode
  this.blueDIV = new DOMElement(node, { 
    properties:{
      'background-color':'#49afeb'
    } 
  });

  var mb = new Box({
    mass: 10,
    size: [50, 200, 10],
    position: new Vec3(window.innerWidth / 2, 0, 0)
  });

  this.gravity = new Gravity1D(mb, {direction: Gravity1D.DOWN,     strength: 500});

  this.floor = new Wall({direction: Wall.UP, friction: 0});
  this.floor.setPosition(0, window.innerHeight, 0);

  this.collision = new Collision([mb, this.floor]);
  this.distance = new Distance(mb,this.floor);

  this.simulation.add([mb, this.gravity, this.collision]);
  console.log("hey");

  return mb;
}

FamousEngine.init();

var test = new Game();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scene` is the start of the engine scene graph. Use it as the context rather than the parent node. So we will first isolate it outside our class scope in this case and adding a starting scene node as the top of the scene graph.

```js
//create scene graph
var scene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');

var camera = new Camera(scene);
camera.setDepth(1000);

//Physics engine test
function Game(sceneNode) {
  this.simulation = new PhysicsEngine();

  this.node = sceneNode.addChild();
  this.node
    .setSizeMode('absolute', 'absolute', 'absolute')
    .setAbsoluteSize(50, 200)
    .setPosition(0, 0, 0)
    .setMountPoint(0.5, 1);

  this.line = this.node.addChild();
  this.line
    .setAbsoluteSize(50, 10)
    .setSizeMode(1, 1, 1)
    .setAlign(0.0, 0.5); //need to make function to radomize this
  var mark = new DOMElement(this.line, {
    properties: {
      'background-color': '#FF0000'
    }
  });


  var position = new Position(this.node);
  this.myBox = createBox.call(this, this.node, position);

  console.log('this.myBox', this.myBox);

  var element = new DOMElement(sceneNode);
  sceneNode.addUIEvent('click');
  sceneNode.onReceive = function(event, payload) {
    if (event === 'click') {
      var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();
      // var bp = this.myBox.getPosition();
      console.log(itemPosition.y - 100);
    }
  }.bind(this);

  FamousEngine.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this);
  console.log(this);
}
.
.
.

FamousEngine.init();

var root = scene.addChild();
var game = new Game(root);
```

The `click` event needs a `DOMElement` on the node that is the size of our scene, so we add one to the root node.

```js
  var element = new DOMElement(sceneNode);
  sceneNode.addUIEvent('click');
  sceneNode.onReceive = function(event, payload) {
    if (event === 'click') {
      var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();
      // var bp = this.myBox.getPosition();
      console.log(itemPosition.y - 100);
    }
  }.bind(this);
```

#### Here is the Example snippet

```js
//var famous = require('famous');

var FamousEngine = famous.core.FamousEngine;
var Camera = famous.components.Camera;
var DOMElement = famous.domRenderables.DOMElement;

var math = famous.math;
var physics = famous.physics;
var PhysicsEngine = famous.physics.PhysicsEngine;
var Box = physics.Box;
var Vec3 = math.Vec3;
var Size = famous.components.Size;
var Position = famous.components.Position;
var MountPoint = famous.components.MountPoint;
var Gravity1D = physics.Gravity1D;
var Collision = physics.Collision;
var Distance = physics.Distance;
var Wall = physics.Wall;

//create scene graph
var scene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');

var camera = new Camera(scene);
camera.setDepth(1000);

//Physics engine test
function Game(sceneNode) {
  this.simulation = new PhysicsEngine();

  this.node = sceneNode.addChild();
  this.node
    .setSizeMode('absolute', 'absolute', 'absolute')
    .setAbsoluteSize(50, 200)
    .setPosition(0, 0, 0)
    .setMountPoint(0.5, 1);

  this.line = this.node.addChild();
  this.line
    .setAbsoluteSize(50, 10)
    .setSizeMode(1, 1, 1)
    .setAlign(0.0, 0.5); //need to make function to radomize this
  var mark = new DOMElement(this.line, {
    properties: {
      'background-color': '#FF0000'
    }
  });


  var position = new Position(this.node);
  this.myBox = createBox.call(this, this.node, position);

  console.log('this.myBox', this.myBox);

  var element = new DOMElement(sceneNode);
  sceneNode.addUIEvent('click');
  sceneNode.onReceive = function(event, payload) {
    if (event === 'click') {
      var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();
      // var bp = this.myBox.getPosition();
      console.log(itemPosition.y - 100);
    }
  }.bind(this);

  FamousEngine.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this);
  console.log(this);
}

Game.prototype.onUpdate = function(time) {
  this.simulation.update(time);

  var itemPosition = this.myBox.getPosition();

  // console.log(itemPosition);
  //console.log(itemPosition.x, itemPosition.y, itemPosition.z);
  this.node.setPosition(itemPosition.x, itemPosition.y, itemPosition.z);
  FamousEngine.requestUpdateOnNextTick(this);
};

//add node - this node will be static
//create box
function createBox(node, position) {
  //attach a DOM element component to the staticNode
  this.blueDIV = new DOMElement(node, {
    properties: {
      'background-color': '#49afeb'
    }
  });

  var mb = new Box({
    mass: 10,
    size: [50, 200, 10],
    position: new Vec3(window.innerWidth / 2, 0, 0)
  });

  this.gravity = new Gravity1D(mb, {
    direction: Gravity1D.DOWN,
    strength: 500
  });

  this.floor = new Wall({
    direction: Wall.UP,
    friction: 0
  });
  this.floor.setPosition(0, window.innerHeight, 0);

  this.collision = new Collision([mb, this.floor]);
  this.distance = new Distance(mb, this.floor);

  this.simulation.add([mb, this.gravity, this.collision]);
  console.log("hey");

  return mb;
}

FamousEngine.init();

var root = scene.addChild();
var game = new Game(root);
```

```css
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            body {
                position: absolute;
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
                -webkit-perspective: 0;
                perspective: none;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?v=1" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.6.2/famous.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```